# Why I can't save my python Class into a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, class

I'm making an expense tracker. I've created an Account class, that registers a specific budget. All the accounts are saved in a Budgets list. Then I try to save the Budgets list into a json file using the save function, which returns an error. This is kinda obvious, but I can't think of any efficient alternative. Any solution? PD: I deleted all the structure not related with the problem, because it already works, and it doesn't let me send all the code. Sorry if something seems out of context.

```
def initialize(filename):
   """
   Adjusts the starting parameters.
   """

   budgets = []

   try: 
   # Checks if the file exists, and executes the apropiate code
   # according to the situation.
       with open(filename, 'r') as f_obj: 
           budgets = json.load(f_obj) 
           # Loads the info from older sessions 
           # into the list.

   except FileNotFoundError: #If the file doesn't exist, we create it.
       print("Seems you are the first one here!")

       return budgets




class Account:
   """

   Simulates a budget with custom percentatges for each area of spending

   """
   def __init__(self, name, cash, percent):
       self.name = name
       self.cash = int(cash)
       self.percent = percent
       self.budget = {}

       for key, value in self.percent.items():
           self.budget[key] = self.cash * value / 100


def save(filename, budgets):
   """Saves the changes made into the accounts"""

   with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj: 
       json.dump(budgets, f_obj)

def main():
   """Executes the main program"""

   filename = "budgets.json"

   budgets = initialize(filename)

   while True:
       a = input("\nSelect the desired operation (h for help): ")

       if a == 'help':
           help()


       elif a == 'save':
           save(filename, budgets)
           print('account saved succesfully')

       elif a == 'exit':
           break

       else:
           print("ERROR: The input is not an operation\n")
```

Comment: can you add the error and traceback?

Comment: `f_obj.write(json.dump(budgets))`

Comment: See the documentation of the `json` module to learn out to teach `json.dumps` how to serialize an instance of your custom class.

Comment: So far as I can tell, your `initialise` function will only return something if the file doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really not sure about my solution, but!!! If I remember correctly, you
can only serialize dictionaries in json, so maybe try this out:

```py
def save(filename, budgets):
   """Saves the changes made into the accounts"""

   with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj: 
       budgets2 = [budget.__dict__ for budget in budgets]
       json.dump(budgets2, f_obj)
```

Comment: Actually works, and it also does the opposite way when o Load the dict from older sessions into the acc class. Thanks! :)